# How to call public Java variable in FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying to call a Java method in my FreeMarker template that uses a public static Java variable as one of its parameters. For example, if the FreeMarker code in a `test.ftl` is this:

```
${javaClass.getSomething(javaClass.VARIABLE)}
```

and if the class `JavaClass` looks like this:

```
public class JavaClass {

    public static final int VARIABLE = 1;

    public String getSomething(int var) {
    ...
    }
```

I receive errors when using the template that look like this:

`[echo] Expression JavaClass is undefined on line 40, column 81 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl.
     [echo] The problematic instruction:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] 03:53:01,146 ERROR [main][runtime:96] Template processing error: "Expression JavaClass is undefined on line 40, column 81 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl"
     [echo]
     [echo] ==> ${javaClass.getSomething(javaClass.VARIABLE)} [on line 40, column 25 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl] Expression JavaClass is undefined on line 40, column 81 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl.
     [echo]
     [echo] ----------The problematic instruction:
     [echo]
     [echo]
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Java backtrace for programmers:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] ==> ${javaClass.getSomething(javaClass.VARIABLE)} [on line 40, column 25 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl]freemarker.core.InvalidRe
ferenceException: Expression JavaClass is undefined on line 40, column 81 in com/test/template/path/test.ftl.
...
...`

This error is complaining that it doesn't like the `javaClass.VARIABLE` and throws the `InvalidReferenceException`. I've tried specifying this in other different ways, such as `JavaClass.VARIABLE`, `${javaClass.VARIABLE}`, and `${JavaClass.VARIABLE}`, but they all throw errors.

How would you call a public Java variable from within a Java method in a FreeMarker (.ftl) template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freemarker's data model doesn't map static fields on objects passed in automatically, so you'd have to use a beanwrapper http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html.

```
import freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper;

BeansWrapper w = new BeansWrapper(); 
TemplateHashModel statics = w.getStaticModels();
model.addAttribute("myVariable", statics);
```

then in your template, use

```
${myVariable["fully.qualified.package.ClassName"].FIELD_NAME}
```

Comment: It's better to use the `ObjectWrapper` used in the `Configuration`, assuming it's a `BeansWrapper` subclass (like a `DefaultObjectWrapper`).

Comment: Also it's probably nicer to do `model.addAttribute("ClassName", statics.get(ClassName.class.getName()))`, so then in the template you can simply write `${ClassName.FIELD_NAME}`.

Comment: yea, fair enough - making the key the classname and then adding the model for that class individually is probably nicer.